# Character Encoding interferes with matching Scala strings?

Tags: string, scala, character-encoding, pattern-matching

Right now dealing with a weird problem when trying to match two Scala strings. When trying to determine if the following two strings are the same:

`SM8lz5IEIWs7TUhR3ke27pnY3XsjojxqaMEg+ARCGs1nm3sVkwA+CM+XJfdsUxqzqH7LZdkflvny 
z621tYkmXA==` and `SM8lz5IEIWs7TUhR3ke27pnY3XsjojxqaMEg+ARCGs1nm3sVkwA+CM+XJfdsUxqzqH7LZdkflvny 
z621tYkmXA==`

Scala returns `false`. So if I do the following `if(hash1 == hash2)` it returns `false`.

I suspect this is either a whitespace or character encoding issue, since hash matching only fails when trying to match a hash that was produced on a computer of a different operating system. I already tried stripping whitespace using regex, but it still failed.

What have I overlooked? And are there better ways to clean and match hashes in Scala?

### Update

After comparing the two strings, Scala thinks `hash2` is a single character longer than `hash1`. So I ran the following functions on both hashes: `.trim.replaceAll("""(?m)\s+$""", "")`. Still, it says they're not the same. What other characters could be interfering?

Comment: I've tried it on osx 10.8, and hashes compares to "true". You can try to run `hash1.diff(hash2)` to see if there is some actual difference (it should yield symbols that do not match).

Comment: Just realized Scala thinks one is a single character longer than the other. Going to post an update.

Comment: Try printing the following (where `s1` and `s2` are your two string): `s1.zip(s2).zipWithIndex.find{ case ((c1, c2), i) => c1 != c2 }`. This will tell you at what index they start to diverge, and what are the two different characters. This should help pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of this particular problem. Apparently when processing strings on Macintosh, `\r` is added in addition to any line breaks. Even though line break characters don't print out on a console, they're still inside the string.

The remedy was to do the following: `.trim.replaceAll("\r", "")`

And now both strings match.

Comment: Don't you want to decode them properly before comparing them?

Comment: I was originally generating a new `UTF-8` string using the bytes from the original. But are you suggesting to go further than that?

Comment: I presumed the gibberish in your example was not the actual data, but rather some kind of encoding (quoted printable or base64 or some such), though I don't recognize the exact format. Is that the case?

Comment: It's a hash between a password and salt. However, I then re-processed it by getting the bytes from the hash and then generating something like `new String(hash.getBytes, "UTF-8")` which comes out to the same. Does that explain it?

Comment: Yes. However, if those bytes are arbitrary 8-bit values, you run a real risk of a failure to encode to UTF-8 characters. If they're "merely" bytes (not encoded characters), then you should not be trying to treat them as if they were `Char`. Basically, what you have is _not_ a `String` and you should not try to pretend it is.

Comment: Good point and you're right. I'm going to need to add some thought to this.